# Visual Studio code - Elixir formatter not working, trying to use prettier instead

Tags: visual-studio-code, elixir, formatter

When pressing save VS.code is not formatting Elixir files, even after installing the elixir-ls extension https://github.com/elixir-lsp/elixir-ls

VS.Code is trying to use Prettier as the default formatter and the option `format with` doesn't show other formatters.

Answer (score 9):

We can define different formatters based in the language we are using, under `settings.json` in user space we can specify the configurations for Elixir.

On my file I used:

```
  "[elixir]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "JakeBecker.elixir-ls"
  },
```

My formatter starts with `JakeBecker` because I have the old plugin still installed in my system, this may or not have changed in the latest version.

Comment: The JakeBecker plugin (https://github.com/elixir-lsp/vscode-elixir-ls) has gotten an update recently and is now again favored over the Elixir-LS fork.